# Automapper bidirectional complex mappings

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, automapper

I'm having troubles configuring Automapper in order to have the expected comportment.

I have 3 entities :

```cs
public abstract class Item
{

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

```cs
public class Ingredient
{

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

}
```

```cs
public class ConstructionItem : Item
{

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<Ingredient> Recipe { get; set; };

}
```

For each entity I have a corresponding dto :

```cs
public abstract class ItemDto
{

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

```cs
public class IngredientDto
{

    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

}
```

```cs
public class ConstructionItemDto : ItemDto
{

    public List<IngredientDto> Recipe { get; set; }

}
```

I also have 2 request models :

```cs
public class CreateConstructionItemRequest {

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<IngredientDto> Recipe { get; set; }

}
```

```cs
public class UpdateConstructionItemRequest {

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<IngredientDto> Recipe { get; set; }

}
```

Questions :

- How can I bind my `CreateConstructionItemRequest` and `UpdateConstructionItemRequest` to an actual `ConstructionItem` ?
- How can I map a `ConstructionItemDto` to `ConstructionItem` and vice versa ?

Thank you for your help !

Edit 1 :

Here is what I've tried :

```cs
public class GeneralProfile : Profile
{
    public GeneralProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Ingredient, IngredientDto>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Item, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Item.Id));

        CreateMap<CreateConstructionItemRequest, ConstructionItem>();

        CreateMap<UpdateConstructionItemRequest, ConstructionItem>();

        CreateMap<ConstructionItem, ConstructionItemDto>();
    }
}
```

Problems :

- Can't map ConstructionItem to ConstructionItemDto
- Can't map CreateConstructionItemRequest to ConstructionItem
- Can't map UpdateConstructionItemRequest to ConstructionItem

Edit 2 :

Error :

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
CreateConstructionItemRequest -> ConstructionItem
MyApp.Application.Features.ConstructionItems.Commands.CreateConstructionItemRequest -> MyApp.Domain.Entities.ConstructionItem

Type Map configuration:
CreateConstructionItemRequest -> ConstructionItem
MyApp.Application.Features.ConstructionItems.Commands.CreateConstructionItemRequest -> MyApp.Domain.Entities.ConstructionItem

Destination Member:
Recipe

 ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
IngredientDto -> Ingredient
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please add what you've tried so far with AutoMapper. BR

Comment: Hi @RoarS. thank you for your answer, I've updated my post with my current `GeneralProfile` configuration.

Comment: If you add the error messages as well, you will have a well-formed question. BR

Comment: Just create two extension methods for those conversions. Much cleaner, less pain, easier to debug, you correctly see if the members are (not) referenced, code breaks immediately if you forget to update the mapping on refactoring, VS will not die in parsing tons of lambdas, and you will not kill performance with heavy reflection and expression evaluation. I just never understood why AutoMapper was so popular. It was a pain in literally every project I had to use it.

Comment: Hi @GyörgyKőszeg thank you for you answer, I will try to do that. Do you have a github link for an example of extension ?

Comment: It's nothing complicated just a pair of manual mapping. Eg. `public static SomeDto ToDto(this Something value) => new SomeDto { Id = value.Id, Name = value.Name };` and a similar one for the opposite direction. For your 3 types you need 2x3 methods for both directions. Parent types and collections should also call the conversion extension methods of mapped the subtypes, eg `Recipe = value.Recipe.Select(ingr => ingr.ToDto()).ToList()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one request model instead of your two models:

```
public class ConstructionItemRequest {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<IngredientDto> Recipe { get; set; }
}
```

and for mapping profile try this:

```
public GeneralProfile()
{
    CreateMap<Ingredient, IngredientDto>().ReverseMap();
    CreateMap<Item, ItemDto>().ReverseMap();            
    CreateMap<ConstructionItemRequest, ConstructionItem>().ReverseMap();
    CreateMap<ConstructionItem, ConstructionItemDto>().ReverseMap();
}
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your response, I've done one modification which is `CreateMap<Ingredient, IngredientDto>().ForMember(x => x.Item, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Item.Id)).ReverseMap();`, In fact I'm mapping the `Id` to the `Item.Id`. The reverse map is not working. I'm getting this error : `Destination Member:
Item

 ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Guid -> Item`

Comment: It is obvious that Item.Id with Guid type cannot be mapped to Item type. Do this:  CreateMap<Ingredient, IngredientDto>().ForMember(x => x.ItemId, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Item.Id)).ReverseMap();

Comment: My `x.Item` is of type Guid

Comment: you have Item in Ingredient class which is in type of Item and ItemId in IngredientDto class with type of Guid. these two types cannot be converted to each other using AutoMapper. As I wrote above you can simply map Item.Id to ItemId which are of the same type.